# Let $f_n (x)= \dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n }$. Show that $f_n$ is integrable for $n\geq 2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq 2$, consider the functions
$f_n : (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f_n (x)= \dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n }$$

1. Show that $f_n$ is integrable (Lebesgue) for $n\geq 2$.
2. Show that for $n\geq 2$, $x\geq 1$, $f_n (x)\leq \dfrac{4}{x^2}$.
3. Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{(0,+\infty)} f_n (x) dx$.

I think for part 3 I should use the Dominated Convergence Theorem by using part 2 for the interval $[1, \infty)$, but then I should prove that $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is integrable in that interval right?

For part 1 and 2 I don't have any idea, so any help would be appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $n \geq 2$ and notice that

\begin{align*}
0 < x < 1
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad x^{1/n} \geq \sqrt{x} \quad\text{and}\quad \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \geq 1 \\
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad f_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
\end{align*}

and that

\begin{align*}
x \geq 1
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad x^{1/n} \geq 1 \quad\text{and}\quad \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \geq 1 + \binom{n}{1}\frac{x}{n}+\binom{n}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2} \geq \frac{x^2}{4} \\
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad f_n(x) \leq \frac{4}{x^2}.
\end{align*}

This already proves part (2). Moreover, we obtain the dominating function

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-1/2}, & 0 < x < 1 \\ 4x^{-2}, & x \geq 1 \end{cases} $$

which is integrable:

$$ \int_{(0,\infty)} g(x) \, dx
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{x^2} \, dx
= 2 + 4 = 6 < \infty. $$

Since $0 \leq f_n \leq g$ and $g$ is integrable, the same is true for $f_n$ when $n \geq 2$. This resolves part (1). Finally, applying the dominated convergence theorem

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{(0,\infty)} f_n(x) \, dx
= \int_{(0,\infty)} \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \, dx
= \int_{(0,\infty)} e^{-x} \, dx
= 1. $$

Comment: Wow thank you ! Just one more thing, in the last part, why does $f_n (x) \to e^{-x}$ as $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @user392559, Have you never seen the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$? There are multiple ways to show this, and one possible approach would be to compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} n \log(1 + \frac{x}{n}) = x$.

Comment: I think I have already seen that before. But how is it that the integral of $e^{-x}$ is 1?

Comment: @user392559, I really have no idea where you can be possibly stuck at computing the integral. If you know how to compute the anti-derivative $\int e^{-x} = -e^{-x} + C$, I wonder what prevents you from getting an answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for that, sometimes I get confused about Riemann and Lebesgue integration, but in this case they are the same because the function is Riemann-integrable and I didn't notice that. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @user392559, I see, that is a valid point. Strictly speaking, improper Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral differ for some class of functions (with the Dirichlet integral  being an archetypal example), so the computation $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, dx = 1$ is not a free gift. But it is not hard to check that if a non-negative function is improperly Rimeann integrable, then it is also Lebesgue integrable and two integrals coincide. Then the same is true for absolutely convergent improper Riemann integrals.